# how to reload div with jquery and keep addEventListener working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have a problem when updating the "div", the refresh works well, however after the refresh when I click on the "div" which has just been updated I no longer have any reaction of my addEventListener javascript , why? and how to deal with this problem?
thank you in advance.

here exemple onclick run perfect :

> `function updateDiv() {  $( "#here" ).load(window.location.href + " #here" ); }`

but after the function bellow won't run anymore:

> `document.getElementById("here").addEventListener("click", () => { alert(" hello world !") }`

Comment: Please create a minimal runnable example.

Comment: First, why the mix of jQuery and javascript? Also as Reporter said, please create a minimal working example of the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

try adding onclick event like this

```js
function updateDiv() {  $("#here").load(window.location.href + " #here");
$("#here").attr("onclick","alert()");
}

function alert(){

alert(" hello world !");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval()` It may help you.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/31940504)

Comment: @ZachJensz I don't see how this is a covert comment. To me it attempts to answer the question, although it could use a little explanation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use passive event listener to keep them even if the element is created/destroyed/reloaded at runtime

```js
function updateDiv() {  $("#here").load(window.location.href + " #here");}



$("#here").on("click", () => { alert(" hello world !") })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="here">here</div>
<button onclick="updateDiv()">Click here</button>
```